# The view past events button has disappeared from manage events. How do I view/copy from past events?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Using civiCRM-5.35.1-wordpress, and since updating the view past events button under Manage Events has disappeared. Does anyone know where this has gone? Is it now accessible somewhere else? Thanks for your help!
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the past events by doing a search based on dates

[image]

Comment: That's how it used to look. Now the Find events bit is missing.

Comment: I've added a screenshot in my question to show what it looks like now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check if its hidden?

Comment: I'm not sure where to check. I don't think I've ever tried to hide/show it before. Please could you help me find where that option is? Thanks.